# C# How to Highlight Current DataGridVeiw Cell in Focus

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview, cell

I have a `DataGridView` for which, upon invalidating a cell value, I'd like to highlight the cell (even if it is the current cell) so that the user may see the value of the cell be replaced by any key press.  If have tried both of these with no joy:

```
dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
```

...and...

```
dgv.ClearSelection();
dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I like the cell with invalid data to go from looking like this:

[image]

...to looking something like this (I filled the space in Paint) :

[image]

I'm presently doing this in the `CellValidating` event handler for `DataGridView`.  Would this work better in the `CellValidated` event handler?

Comment: Have you tried with `Selected` property?

Comment: Yes, setting the `Selected` property is shown as my second approach in the post.

Comment: Oooppss, i missed that. Can you define what you mean by "highlight cell"? You mean, you want to set focus in it to be able to edit that cell? If yes, try `BeginEdit(true)` method.

Comment: The DGV already uses SystemColors.Highlight to mark what is selected, what else are you looking to do?

Comment: Is the dgv.SelectionMode set to CellSelect?

Comment: @Plutonix I don't want to merely colorize the cell.  I want the cell to actually be selected, so that any user input will cause the cell value to change.

Comment: @JerryM I tried changing the `SelectionMode` to `CellSelect` but now joy.

Comment: I added some details to the OP.  I'm presently doing this in the `CellValidating` event handler for `DataGridView`.  Would this work better in the `CellValidated` event handler?

Comment: the typical way to call out errors is to use `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText` or `dgv2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText` if there is room - it allows you tell them *what* is wrong if you like

Comment: @Plutonix I'm already doing that.  Thanks.  I'd just like to make it a little easier for my users to fix their data entry, rather than potentially frustrating users while they figure out how to fix what may be obvious to me.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I dont understand the question.  "Highlighting in cell focus", reporting errors and fixing errors are all different things.  I dont see how painting a cell fixes anything.

Comment: @Plutonix Your right. Painting a cell does nothing.  That's not what I'm asking.   I want the cell to be selected, so that any user input (i.e. pressing a letter or a number on the keyboard) will cause the cell value to change.  This would be similar behavior as when the `DataGridView` is first populated, and the user clicks on a cell with the mouse.

Comment: When you click on a cell, it's selected and highlighted by default and it will receive all input keys and starts editing. What do you need additional to this?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Instead of requiring my user to backspace over the offending text, or try to figure out which cell has invalid data, I'd prefere for the cell in question to become automatically (dynamically/programmatically) highlighted to make it obvious to the user where the problem lies.  This has the added benefit of causing the cell value to change on any keystroke.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:  `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[2];`? Also you can force it to enter to edit mode if you need: `dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Unfortunately, I've tried that, but it didn't work.  While it is true that the user is able to edit the cell, the cell remains in what I will call "text edit mode," which is not obviously an editable cell without close attention to detail.  It also requires the user to backspace over their previously entered text.

Comment: Check it like I did in the answer. I checked it and it works properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a cell as current cell of `DataGridView` you can assign it to [`CurrentCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx) property of it:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2];
```

To force the current cell to go to edit mode, you can use [`BeginEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

To deselect all selected cells, you can use [`ClearSelection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clearselection(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

To change the background color of active cell when it's in edit mode, handle [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] == dataGridView1.CurrentCell)
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Would changing the selected cell to a different cell and then back to my desired cell perhaps have the desired results of highlighting the entire cell?

Comment: The `CurrentCell` is the cell that the user is presently editing and is presently being validated in my `CellValidating` event handler.

Comment: The way I test this solution is: I have a grid and a button and I write these codes in `Click` event handler of `Button` and it works properly.

Comment: Check also the `CellFormatting` option which I added to asnwer which highlights active cell, even in edit mode.

Comment: The last option changes the background color of editing cell, isn't it what you are looking for?